# How to fix fontWeight value for <Text> component in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I have a problem with font weight of `<Text>` inside Custom Button Component.

```js
export const TouchableButton = (props) => {
  const { label, onPress } = props;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={{ borderRadius: 16, backgroundColor: Colors.primary, paddingHorizontal: 25, paddingVertical: 15 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: '500' }}>{label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

It didn't work on android but only if I'm using imported TouchableButton. (In iphone emulator it works)

What is the reason of this behavior and how to resolve this properly?

I'm using

```json
{
   "react-native": "0.71.8",
   "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
   "expo": "^48.0.0"
}
```

I manually insert same customButton code in my page and everything works good.

Comment: question need formatting